# C# variable scopes and the "switch" statement?

Tags: c#, scope

This kind of code would normally work in PHP, but since the scope is much more strict in C#, it's not.  I can't figure out a way to write this code without repeating myself.

```
    static double Cube()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the side length of the cube: ");
        try
        {
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Read());
            return Math.Pow(x, 3);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter a number.");
            Cube();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

..Later in Main():

```
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:
                    double final = Cube();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0 or 1.");
                    Main();
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The volume is: {0}", Convert.ToString(final));
```

The `Cube()` method works fine, but it's messy in my opinion (`return 1` at the end to make the compiler happy).  But an error comes up saying **The name 'final' does not exist in the current context**.  It can't find final.  So the only way to make this work that I'm seeing is to put the `Console.WriteLine` statement right after the double final = Cube().

I've also tried declaring `double final;` outside the switch, then just setting `final` inside each case, but that hasn't worked either.

Thanks!

Comment: "Hasn't worked either" (wrt the other things tried) is wrong/misleading. They would have 1) worked or 2) resulted in a different error.

Comment: You have to put `return 1` because your definition of Cube is messy.  It does too many things and your use of recursion inside the catch isn't very clean either.  The function must return a value, so you arbitrarily picked 1 as the failure case return.  If you don't like that, move Math.Pow and decide where you can actually get the correct error behavior at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access `final` from outside the `switch` scope, you'll have to declare it outside that scope too. If you reference `final` and there are code paths that allow not setting a value to `final`, then the compiler will be "angry".

In php, `final` would magically be 0 when you don't assign anything to it. Try declaring `final` before the switch, and then assign a value to it at each `case` statement including the `default` case.

Answer (score 19):

You're right: this is a mess. Start over.

Your fundamental problem is that you're not separating your concerns. You have a method that does user input, input validation, retry logic and math all at the same time. You should rather make methods for each.

Also, use TryParse to handle the failure case, not exception handling.

Finally, recursion is completely the wrong tool to use. A problem **must** have the following characteristics to be solved by recursion:

- A trivial base case.
- Can be reduced to a set of smaller problems.
- Solutions to smaller problems can be combined to solve larger problems.
- Making a problem smaller repeatedly eventually gets to the trivial case.

Your problem has *none* of these properties, so recursion is automatically the wrong tool. The tool you want is a *loop*.

```
static void Main()
{
    double x = ObtainDoubleFromUser(
        "Enter the side length of the cube: ", 
        "Please enter a number: ");
    Console.WriteLine("The volume is {0}", Cube(x));
}

static double ObtainDoubleFromUser(string firstMessage, string failureMessage)
{
    Console.Write(firstMessage);
    while(true)
    {
        double result;
        if (Double.TryParse(Console.Read(), out result))
            return result;
        Console.Write(failureMessage);
    }
}

static double Cube(double x)
{
    return Math.Pow(x, 3);
}
```

Does that all make sense? You want to avoid recursion and exception handling if you possibly can. And keep your concerns separated.

Comment: I just want to apologize for completely missing this fantastic answer back in '12 - I like to think I have progressed beyond a 'give codes' programmer as I clearly was when I posted this question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Place the variable declaration before your switch statement:

```
double final = 0.0;
switch(choice)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Then just use the variable in your switch statement:

```
case 1:
    final = Cube();
    break;
```

In C#, variables must be declared before they can be used.  In your code, the declaration was limited to the scope of the switch statement.  Declaring the variable prior to the switch statement ensures that its in the scope of the method, allowing it to be used inside and after the switch statement.